# jquery hide one of the options from the drop down onchange

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down for events as below :

```
<select name="event" class="filterSelectBox" onchange="javascript: test();">
                      <option value="disable" id="default" selected="selected">Event Type</option>
            <option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
            <option value="Sangeet">Sangeet</option>
            <option value="Mehendi">Mehendi</option>
            <option value="Youngsters">Youngsters</option>
            <option value="BridalShower">Bridal Shower</option>
            <option value="BabyShower">Baby Shower</option>
            <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
            <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
            <option value="Conference">Conference</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
```

Now the issue is that when someone clicks on the drop-down,the default option which Event type shows up again on the drop down list. So i tried something like this :

```
 <script>
function test()
{
    $(" option[id='events']").hide();
}


</script>
```

That default option still does not hide.

Kindly advice.

Comment: there are no elements with `id='events'`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fpkTd/ it's working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Use `id=default` not `id=events`,

```
function test()
{
    $(" option[id='default']").hide();
}
```

or use `javascript` to `hide` this `option` like,

```
function test()
{
    document.getElementById('default').style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: I did , sorry ..that was an error while copy pasting ..there is no issue with the id selector ...i used the correct one...still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Jquery I'd do like this :

```
$(".filterSelectBox").change(function () 
{
    $(" option[id='default']").hide();
});
```

Working Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SGSP3/

Update to a comment:

If you want it on click then do

```
$(".filterSelectBox").click(function ()
{
   $(" option[id='default']").hide();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SGSP3/1/

Comment: I want the default type to disappear when someone clicks on the drop down ,not when someone selects an option from the list. Thanks

Comment: Then do $(".filterSelectBox").click(function ()

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Eventtype in HTML from onchange to onclick.

Comment: I have done that , could you have a look at this : 

http://studio702.biz/venuevista/ : click on the filter 'Events type' just below the banner...and it still doesnt work

Comment: In Your code of the side is no onclick-event. I have searched for it with firebug on mozilla firefox and i don´t find the onclick-event which is calling your funciton maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="event" class="filterSelectBox" onchange="test(this);">
                      <option value="disable" id="default" selected="selected">Event Type</option>
            <option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
            <option value="Sangeet">Sangeet</option>
            <option value="Mehendi">Mehendi</option>
            <option value="Youngsters">Youngsters</option>
            <option value="BridalShower">Bridal Shower</option>
            <option value="BabyShower">Baby Shower</option>
            <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
            <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
            <option value="Conference">Conference</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
```

I've chnaged the onChange function to test(this) for reference. and then Made some changes to test().

```
<script>
function test(select){
 $("option[value='disable']",select).hide();
}
</script>
```

I hope that this will workout for you.

Comment: I have done that , could you have a look at this : 

http://studio702.biz/venuevista/ : click on the filter 'Events type' just below the banner...and it still doesnt work

Comment: What do you want hide? you can't hide the value changed to. Explain your need.